# Intellij IDEA: JForm preview renders fine, actual app ignores Roboto (font)

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, fonts

I am using the Intellij IDEA to create Swing J Forms in the editor. In the preview of the form, I can see my selected font applied (Roboto), but when I run the app, it doesn´t work (Uses default font). It does work for every other font I have tried except Roboto.

I have already tried reinstalling the font / deleting the form and redoing it.

The font is applied in preview.
[image: The font applied in preview.]

Here it uses the default font.
[image: This uses the default font.]

Comment: Try adding the TTF font files to the JVM that is used to run your app (into `jre\lib\fonts`).

Comment: 1) What is your question? Please [edit] to add one. 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).